# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Open Data Stack Exchange site is badly in need of additional moderators.** For the future of the site, we’ll need **at least three users** from the community to volunteer some time to serve as a moderator of the site. In order for a Stack Exchange site to stick around, we need to know that site has folks on hand who can help ensure the site stays well-moderated and handle on-site issues (like flags, Meta, and review queues). On small sites, the time commitment isn't very high - but [we still ask that sites have three moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614) at all times. Under certain circumstances, it can be possible for a site to continue with only two, but it’s never ideal. It’s critical that at least a couple folks here volunteer their time to help.

**Summary**: Open Data Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **September 26th, 2022** to bring in **3** more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on September 26th, users can [nominate themselves](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On October 3rd, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on meta on October 11th (or October 18th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.